# MongoDB/PHP: update individual value of an array

Tags: php, mongodb

Greetings,

I have the following mongodb object:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("4d0b9c7a8b012fe287547157"),
   "messages": {
     "0": {
       "toUname": "Eamorr3",
       "fromUname": "Eamorr2",
       "time": 1292606586,
       "id": "j7zwr2hzx14d3sucmvp5",
       "subject": "asdf",
       "message": "asdf",
       "read": 0
    }
  },
   "uname": "Eamorr3"
}
```

How do I set "read" to 1 in PHP?

Here's what I've tried sofar to no avail:

update(array('uname'=>$uname),array('$set'=>array('messages'=>array('read')=>'1')));

I'm totally stuck. Any help much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's either

```
update(array('uname'=>$uname),array('$set'=>array('messages.0'=>array('read')=>'1')));
```

or

```
update(array('uname'=>$uname),array('$set'=>array('messages.0.read'=>1));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Do you know how I can search through the array by specifying the id (j7zwr2hzx14d3sucmvp5 in this case) rather than "messages.0". I meant to ask that in the original question...

Comment: Take a look at the "The Positional Operator" section at the bottom of http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.updates.php - looks like what you're looking for.